# what is the advantage in defining continous derivative function vs C0 only in Modelica?

Tags: smoothing, modelica, minimum, derivative

I'm wondering if there is any advantage in Modelica in implementing a derivable function, with continuous derivates for the min(.) function ?

I tried the following for the min(.) function, for x⩾0:

```
1/ f1(x,s) := Smooth(0, noEvent(min(x,s)))
2/ f2(x,s) := Smooth(10, x*(1+(x/s)^60)^(-1/60) )
```

the implementation looks like the following:

```
function Limiter "Function  Limiter"
  input Real x;
  input Real xc(final min=0);
  output Real y;
protected 
  Real mx;
  parameter Real k=3;
  parameter Integer o(
    final min=1,
    max=30) = 30;
  final parameter Integer twoO=2*o;
algorithm 
  mx := noEvent(min(x, k*xc));
  if noEvent(abs(xc)) >= 1 then
    y := mx*(1 + (mx/xc)^twoO)^(-1/twoO);
  else
    y := mx*xc*(xc^twoO + mx^twoO)^(-1/twoO);
  end if;
  annotation (derivative=DerLimiter, inverse(x=InverseLimiter(x=y, xc=xc), xc=InverseLimiter(x=y, xc=x)));
end Limiter;
```

Contrary to f1, I can provide modelica with a derivative function and inverse function of f2 for any x⩾0, which I understand helps the solver in speed.

Owerall, I'm wondering if the implementation of such helpers functions is advantageous in Modelica in terms of speed, or, do I waste my time in finding and implementing these ?

Any feedback and knowledge sharing on that topic is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the application. The drawbacks of the smoothed `min`-function are:

- It takes more time to compute.
- Even if invertible in theory, it may not be invertible in practice far from the turn-over point. Attempting to invert it may also indicate a modeling issue that should be handled in a completely different way.

So I wouldn't use this smoothed `min`-function until I see that it is actually needed in the specific application - and that is missing from the question.

For functions other than `min` and `max` that are non-smooth it may even be more efficient to keep them non-smooth since that allows the solver to quickly detect the discontinuity in derivatives and trigger an event, instead of spending time to track the rapid "continuous" change. (The `smooth` operator is designed to allow this.)

The general advice is that functions that are smooth and invertible should be declared as such - not that every function should be modified to be smooth and invertible.

Comment: While learning Modelica language, I understood that to improve simulation time, I should build models by avoiding, when appropriate, to trigger state events. That is one of my logic in building these continuous derivative functions. So from your post I understand that it is not necessarily the case.

Comment: I add that my goal was to develop general purpose functions, that should help speeding up the Modelica solver (or at least not slowing it), at least that was the intention.